# merge array to array without key?

Tags: php, facebook, multidimensional-array

im trying to make facebook upload photo with random tag friend. 
the program was run correctly but i got stack on the array

```
$args = array(  
    'message' => 'Test Tags Text',  
    "access_token" => $access_token,  
    "image" => $files,
    'tags'    => $id,
);
```

the $id is array friend list here the format

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends'); 
$frand = array_rand( $friends['data'], 20 );

foreach($frand as $fid){ 
    $id[$fid]['tag_uid'] =  $friends['data'][$fid]['id'];
$id[$fid]['x']  = 0;
$id[$fid]['y']  = 0;
}
```

Comment: No, I don't get it. What is the result you want to have? Where is the `$args` array used?

Comment: i need array $id merge to $args without key ... so i need $args => array( $id ) without key >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2:**

Please read about arrays: [PHP manual arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Every element in an array has a key even if you don't specify it. You cannot have an element in an array without key.

There is a difference between *defining* an array, where you don't have to specify keys, and *printing* the array, which gives you a textual representation of the array.

**Update:** So it seems it has to be

```
$args['tags'] = $id;
```

`$id` is already an array. If you pass it to `array`, it will create a new array with the `$id` as first element.

---

**Old answer:**

You are already talking about *merge*. Have you had a look at [**`array_merge`**<sup>[docs]</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)?

```
$args['tags'] = array_merge($args['tags'], $id);
```

---

Of course, `$args['tags'] = array( $id );` does not work. It

1. Overwrites the already existing value of `$args['tags']`.
2. As you already noticed, it adds `$id` which is already an array, to an array. If `$args['tags']` does not have a value, you could just do `$args['tags'] = $id;`.

Comment: using array merge the result have a key [tags] => Array(**[0]** =>Array(
[tag_uid] => 703031848  ..... i want to remove "[0]=>"

Comment: @StecyAulia: But `$args['tags']` is an array of arrays and `$id` is an array of arrays. You cannot remove the key. Only if you just want to have **one** of the elements in `$id` as value. Then the question is (a) why do you already have two values in `$args['tags']` if you only want one and (b) why are you collecting all the values in `$id` if you only want one. As I said, it would be much easier if you provide a concrete example of the output you want to get.

Comment: the first $args[tags] array is sample ... i want strukture array like that ... i need 20 fb id on that

Comment: @StecyAulia: Ah. You didn't say that. Then it is just `$args['tags'] = $id;`

Comment: @StecyAulia: `$args['tags'] = $id;` will create exactly the structure you have above in `$args`. **Of course there is a key, because you multiple tags.** Every array has keys. You cannot have multiple tags without keys. If the `$args` array is correct, so will it be after assigning `$id`. Do you actually try to run the code and see whether it works?

Comment: i wanna make array(array(),array());  **its not have a key**

Comment: @Stecy: It does, haves a look at http://codepad.org/EfRUYvHr . Numerical keys are always **implicit**. Please read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. This is normal!

Comment: @StecyAulia: How? I hope you understood that what you think is wrong, is normal.

Comment: yeah this phpsdk make me ill feel >.< thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using compact($example1,$example2,$example3), but the result will be different than what you might be used to with array merge:

```
$example1 = array (x,y,z);
$example2 = array (a,b,c);
$example3 = array (d,e,f);

$mergedValue = compact('example1','example2','example3');
var_dump ($mergedValue);

// output will be:
array(3) { ["example1"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "x" [1]=> string(1) "y" [2]=> string(1) "z" } ["example2"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" } ["example3"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "d" [1]=> string(1) "e" [2]=> string(1) "f" } }
```

The link to php manual where compact is covered is:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Comment: `compact` is used for something else. And how can your code produce this output?

Comment: @Felix Kling: I am using compact and it works for me. If there is an alternative and a reason not to use compact I would appreciate to learn about it.

Comment: Well, it turned out the the problem was a totally different one. But for merging two arrays, you should not use `compact`. It is just an easy way to create a `variable_name => value` mapping.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Thanks. I recently learned about compact while trying to solve a problem in cakephp, and I had the syntax a bit wrong. I wouldn't use it normally but in cakephp using it in this manner cleans up quite a bit of a mess.